# Alguém pode me explicar esse código?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expressões-lambda

Tem esse seguinte código e estou muito confuso sobre ele, mesmo mexendo com javascript, tentei ir debugando porém coloquei um console.log dentro da função na variavel "T" e ele printa verdade, falso... porém não é passado nenhum parametro para essa T, na realidade acontece ao contrário passam a T dentro do AND, enfim estou bem confuso sobre isso. Só preciso entender o porque de realizar desde o display até o AND etc...

```js
        
        var T = function (a, b) {
        console.log(a,b);
            return a;
        };
        
        var F = function (a, b) {
            return b;
        };
        
        var display = function (b) {
          //console.log(b);
            return b('verdadeiro', 'falso');
        };
        
        var NOT = function (x) {
            return x(F, T);
        };
        
        var AND = function (a, b) {
            return a(b, F);
        };
        
        var OR = function (a, b) {
            return a(t, B);
        };
        
        // agora testando:
        alert(display(AND(T, T))); // Vai exibir Verdadeiro, como deveria.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você passa `T` para a função `AND`:

```
AND(T, T)
```

E ela invoca `T` passando `b` (neste caso, também igual a `T`) e `F`:

```
var AND = function (a, b) {
    return a(b, F);
};
```

A lógica de execução desse código todo é mais ou menos assim:

1. `AND(T, T)` retorna `T(T, F)`
2. `T(T, F)` retorna `T`
3. `display` recebe `T` e retorna `T('verdadeiro', 'falso')`
4. `T('verdadeiro', 'falso')` retorna `'verdadeiro'`

Comment: mas T recebe 2 parâmetros e quando ela retorna  return a(b, F);  Tanto F quanto b(que no caso é outro T) recebem 2 parametros, e ali só chama elas

Comment: Coloquei um complemento na resposta, veja se te esclarece.

Comment: aah ta entendi agora, muito obrigado